# How to do i solve this electrical circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, current-source, superposition

I've been trying to solve this circuit with two current sources: 
[image]

Following is given:

ia = 1mA, ib = 2mA

R1 = 1K, R2 = 0.5K, R3 = 2.2K, R = 4.7K

Personally I've been trying to use KCL to determine the current I through R2 but haven't got much further than lining up a few equations. I do suspect that I might have to superposition and current division to get on the right track, but I am still not entirely sure.

My question is: How would I 'exactly' solve this circuit?

Comment: Show us all of the work you have done so far. Have you tried using superposition? We will help you with specific questions but we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Current source in parallel with a resistor is a strong hint for.....?

Comment: Compute (R3 || R4) and use ib to make a Norton to Thevenin conversion. Take R1 and ia and also perform another Norton to Theven conversion. Now all you have is two voltage sources at opposite ends separated by three resistors. Should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull out R2 and determine the voltage on either side and equiv series R to get a voltage difference before inserting R2 back.

Then compute the I  from the Vequiv voltage difference and total resistance = Left_eq + Right_eq + R2 = Rtot

Answer (score 0):

Superposition. Plain and simple

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUv49a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{x}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_7\\
\\
0=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_\text{y}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_\text{y}+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

I wrote a Mathematica notebook. It featured the following code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ix == I1 + I2, I1 == Ix + I5, I2 == I3 + I7, 
   0 == I3 + I5 + I6, I4 == Iy + I7, I4 == Iy + I6, I1 == (V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == (V2)/R3, I4 == (V2)/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, I4,
    I5, I6, I7, V1, V2}]]
```

Using your values, the code was edited to:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{1*10^(-3) == I1 + I2, I1 == 1*10^(-3) + I5, I2 == I3 + I7, 
   0 == I3 + I5 + I6, I4 == 2*10^(-3) + I7, I4 == 2*10^(-3) + I6, 
   I1 == (V1)/1000, I2 == (V1 - V2)/500, I3 == (V2)/2200, 
   I4 == (V2)/4700}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, V1, V2}]]
```

Solving it gives:

```
{{I1 -> 3447/2069000, I2 -> -(689/1034500), I3 -> 47/51725, 
  I4 -> 22/51725, I5 -> 689/1034500, I6 -> -(1629/1034500), 
  I7 -> -(1629/1034500), V1 -> 3447/2069, V2 -> 4136/2069}}
```

Which gives approximately:

```
{{I1 -> 0.00166602, I2 -> -0.000666022, I3 -> 0.000908652, 
  I4 -> 0.000425326, I5 -> 0.000666022, I6 -> -0.00157467, 
  I7 -> -0.00157467, V1 -> 1.66602, V2 -> 1.99903}}
```